# Comparison structure for "the above"

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-structure, comparison

I want to say something is very simple or short as you see in its description.
What is the brief construction?

- It is that short
- It is as short as above
- It is as short as the above
- It is as short as that is above
- It is as short as is above

I found the first case is common, but what if I really want to point to the above paragraph or description? Then how can I use "above" in it?

Comment: Could you include the paragraph for more context?

Comment: @Sander I just was writing a question in another site where I faced this question, you can find it in the question (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48585/can-i-write-a-paper-out-of-a-simple-idea) there I said "*because it is as short as the above*" in the second paragraph.

Comment: Or you could say "as short as the one above" or "as short as the paragraph above" or "as short as the preceding paragraph".

Comment: @TRomano why you say *OR you could say...*, do you admit the phrases above? I guess half of them are ungrammatical or maybe nonsense

Comment: I would appreciate it more if you could provide the context of where you want to use the answer to know why you're saying the first one is better. That way we'd be able to get a good idea of what you're implying.

Answer (score 1):

> It is as short as the above

Is the best.

Explanation is as the below:

> It is that short

This is grammatically correct, though sounds a little informal.  It could be used to express surprise or emphasis.

> *It is as short as above

Missing the definite article "the" to specify the particular passage that it matches the shortness of.

> It is as short as the above

Very common construction.

> *It is as short as that is above

Grammatical problems - could work with "which": It is as short as that which is above" - but this is longer and more cumbersome than "as short as the above"

> *It is as short as is above

Incorrect grammar - the "is" is unnecessary.

Comment: Please include an explanation of *why* this is the correct one.